# remove none value on a dict in python won't work

Tags: python, mongodb, list, dictionary, nonetype

I want to modify my mongo DB collection data with removing the `None` value. I have a nested dict.

I did a query to get all the db on my db:

```
doc = db.events.find()
for document in doc:
    print  document
```

One printed document looks like this:

```
{ u'_id': u'55f16d2a0f5cb40aa26a6f1b', u'event': {u'values': u'None', u'condition': u'None', u'comment': u'', u'date': u'None', u'delete': u'false'}}
```

So i want to replace all `None` values inside each document, where is None to write `No`, and save the updated document on the DB.

So I did this :

```
def replace_none_values():
  doc = db.events.find()
  for document in doc:
    for key, value in document.items():
        if key == 'event':
           event_part = value
           for key1, value1 in event_part: 
               if value1 is None:
                  document['event'][key1] = 'No'
    db.events.save(document)
replace_none_values()
```

but the code in `for key1, value1 in event_part:`  is not executed. I don't know why, what I'm doing wrong here? Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the parentheses are missing when you call `replace_none_values`

use:

```
replace_none_values()
```

instead of:

```
replace_none_values
```

Comment: I modified the question , because that mistake  i did while writing the question, anyway  the error that I have is somewhere else.

Comment: In this case the answer of @moses-koledoye is your best bet

Answer (score 0):

Use the `items` method again since what you have is a *nested dictionary*. And note that the values in the dictionary are not the constant `None`, but string `'None'` so `if value1 is None` isn't going to do what you intend:

```
for key1, value1 in event_part.items(): 
#                                ^
     if value1 == 'None':
         document['event'][key1] = 'No'
```

---

And then call the function: `replace_none_values()`